# Data stored inside JSON object in Android is not available in the variable outside of it

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to store the data I receive from the API call in the variable "data". However, the value of data is only updated inside the jsonObjectRequest and it is empty outside of it. How can I make it so that the value of data is available outside the jsonObjectRequest as well?(So I don't have to use the if(i==4) statement)

D/Inside Call: [https://i.redd.it/4tb9k1ray1f91.jpg, https://i.redd.it/4tb9k1ray1f91.jpg, https://i.redd.it/4tb9k1ray1f91.jpg, https://i.redd.it/4tb9k1ray1f91.jpg, https://i.redd.it/yftkun6o43f91.gif]

D/Outside Call: []

```
val data:ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
        for(i in 0 until 5){
            val jsonObjectRequest=JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,url,null,{
                    val value:String=it.getString("url")
                    data.add(value)
                    if(i==4) {
                        mAdapter.updateData(data)
                    }
                    Log.d("Inside Call",data.toString())

                },{}
            )

            MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest)


        }
         Log.d("Outside Call",data.toString())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption of "inside" and "outside" calls is wrong. What you call the inside code is a callback that is, as the name suggests, called when your app has obtained the response to your request. The outside call is executed as soon as you've sent your requests, which is likely to be prior to receiving the responses.

Treat the "inside" code as the "outside" code and you may get closer to your aim. It is the code that will be called when you're "ready" to update your views, in simple terms.

Your `i == 4` check is also error prone because it is not guaranteed that you'll get responses to your requests in the same order you've sent them. How you resolve this depends on your specific use case, so it's difficult to offer absolute solutions. You may be able to get away with using a counter that is incremented in the callback each time a response is obtained, and check if the counter has hit its max value (i.e., all responses have been obtained).